# ansible - how to define var's value depending on ansible_facts

Tags: java, ansible, ansible-role

I'm writing an ansible playbook for installing jdk.

The logic is to use version 8 if the system is "Ubuntu", but 1.8.0 if it is "CentOS".

following is my code:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    - java_open_jdk_version_major: 8
      when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
    - java_open_jdk_version_major: 1.8.0
      when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
  roles:
    - name: jdk
```

In this way, the “java_open_jdk_version_major” always becomes 1.8.0.

How to define variables in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do something like this:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    - java_open_jdk_version_major: "{{ '1.8.0' if ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' else '8' }}"
  roles:
    - name: jdk
```

Comment: thank you very much, this solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you always end up with version as "1.8.0", is because your variables definition is a list and `when` conditionals are not doing anything there.

When `java_open_jdk_version_major` is evaluated first, its value is "8", but another definition is found below, which is "1.8.0", and lastly evaluated value wins.

Another way to achieve this, and *ensure that appropriate versions are set for the respective Distribution* (`CentOS` and `Ubuntu`) is to use a `pre_tasks` section, like so:

```yaml
- hosts: all

  pre_tasks:
    - name: set JDK major version for CentOS
      set_fact:
        java_open_jdk_version_major: "1.8.0"
      when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'

    - name: set JDK major version for Ubuntu
      set_fact:
        java_open_jdk_version_major: "8"
      when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'

  roles:
    - name: jdk
```